# Props value passing style differences in Svelte components

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

I saw many styles of passing a prop value in a svelte components like,

1. `<MyComponent color={"#b291ff7a"} />`
2. `<MyComponent color="#b291ff7a" />`
3. `<MyComponent color={value} />`
4. `<MyComponent color="{value}" />`

What are their differences and when should I use which one?

Just asking for clarifiction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This are the main differences

`<MyComponent color={"#b291ff7a"} />`

- value is passed as string.

`<MyComponent color="#b291ff7a" />`

- value is passed as string also, but the component might not receive it as expected. So it is not recommended.

`<MyComponent color={value} />`

- passing the value variable as it is.

`<MyComponent color="{value}" />`

- passing the value of the variable as string not matter what it is.